# "db:migrate rake" throwing eror "cannot load such file -- bundler/setup"

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I'm a ruby on rails beginner, and I'm trying to run a rails app on my local mac. I have set up the environment and MySQL database, and it was all smoothie  until the last setup step: `db:migrate rake`. I got the following error:

```
cannot load such file -- bundler/setup
/Users/snailwalker/vietnam/snailwalker/config/boot.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/snailwalker/vietnam/snailwalker/config/application.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/snailwalker/vietnam/snailwalker/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
```

What am I missing?

Comment: `db:migrate rake` will return, `db:migrate: command not found`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> cannot load such file -- bundler/setup

Most probably the reason of this issue is that you don't have `bundler`. You should install bundler then try to run migrations again.

```
gem install bundler
bundle install
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

Hope it'll help you.

Comment: Hello,Thank you for replying me so quick, i have been jumping around, I would like to ask one more question, For now i have a rails app from a friend , it's developed under {ruby: 1.9.3-p194; rails: 3.2.8;database: mysql; web server: nginx + unicorn }, But the environment on my mac is newer, and i have Rails 4.1.5; and i would like to use postgres as database, is it possible to run app by modifying the database.yml and gem file after that rake db:migrate? Or i have to install Mysql first then convert the Db to postgres.

Comment: You should be added another question, because from comments no one else can get help. Anyways, you should modify `database.yml` and run  `rake db:migrate`.. Is your `bundler/setup` issue has been solved?

Comment: Thank u very much, i took it too complicated